# Adding blank cells in huge file

Tags: perl, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a huge file that looks like:

```
125552552
126382233
454654654
548652545
876544545
```

I want to add 25 blank cells that way:

```
                                       125552552
                                       126382233
                                       454654654
                                       548652545
                                       876544545
```

I know that there is a way to do that via awk or sed...

Comment: `sed 's/^/                        /'` (where I typed 25 spaces but SO Markdown probably removed most of them; it's better with some `&nbsp;` non-breaking spaces, but damn fiddly).

Comment: seems like a X-Y problem.  What will the spaces be used for in the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these read each line of the file `filename` and print it out with 25 blank spaces prepending it, what is all redirected to a file. You can use either

```
perl -ne 'print " " x 25 . $_' filename  > outfile
```

or

```
perl -pe '$_ = " " x 25 . $_' filename   > outfile
```

The commands are the same for all practical purposes, and both read the file line by line which is what you want if the file is large. The `> outfile` redirects the output to a file with that name.

---

Each of the examples above is a complete command-line program, that is entered and executed in the terminal. The switches

- `-e` means that everything that is in between the following single quotes, `'...'`, is to be executed by Perl as a program.  It can be any valid Perl code.

However, these *one-liner* mini programs come with extra conveniences.

- `-n` sets up a loop over the standard input, so a file submitted after the command (`filename` above) is read line by line and whatever code is between `''` is executed on each of its lines in turn. So we don't have to open a file and loop over its lines by hand.
- `-p` does the same as `-n` with an additional convenience -- it prints the line once it's processed. So if we want each line printed we can use `-p` and don't have to say `print`.  The second example above uses this.
- `-i` change the input file "in-place," used below. A backup can be made as well, see docs.
- Each line is read into the default variable `$_`, and many facilities in Perl operate on it by default (if no variable is passed to them). For example, to print a line we often just say `print`. Here each line needs to be manipulated so I explicitly use `$_` but most of the time we don't.

There is quite a bit more, see [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

---

Note, provided by [`andlrc`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887539/andlrc) in a comment -- one can also use the`$"` for single white space

```
perl -pe '$_ = $"x25 . $_' filename  > outfile
```

From [Special Variables in `perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables)

> - $"
>     When an array or an array slice is interpolated into a double-quoted string or a similar context such as /.../ , its elements are separated by this value. Default is a space.

---

To change the original file add the switch `-i`, for "in-place."  This works with either version above

```
perl -i -ne 'print " " x 25 . $_' filename
```

After this the input `filename` will have been changed (so that each line has 25 spaces prepended). It is possible to have a backup of the original file saved, see [`Command switches in perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches).

Comment: `-p` doesn't chomp input, `-l` does (which also sets `$\ = "\n"`). You can reassign `$_` with `-p`: `perl -pe '$_ = $"x25 . $_' filename`

Comment: @andlrc  Oh ... thank you. I forget and mix them up sometimes, and it's annoying.  Thank you.  That trick with `$"x25` I had _no idea_ about! I'm adding it, and have to loop it up  :) Thank you :).

Comment: Using `-l`  which sets: `$\ = "\n"`, which is prepended to each print statement. Try running: `perl -e 'print for 1..3'` vs  `perl -le 'print for 1..3'`

Comment: A good way to figure out what each flag do is running: `perl -MO=Deparse -e ''`, eg: `perl -MO=Deparse -n -e ''`

Comment: @andlrc Yes, thank you, that's probably why I mixed them up.  I removed it, the point here was to have it simple and clear.  Thanks for `$"`, I didn't actually know about that one at all.  I use `Deparse`, it's such a great tool. I used it for a post here recently, one-liner actually.  Thank you for fixing this :)

Comment: Using `$"` is a bad golfing habit and I wouldn't recommend it in production code. But it's still nice. Going off topic: There are many cool of these, to name a few `$=` which is casting to int, `$.` which is true after each line read as it contains the line number of the last used fh. `$/` which defaults to a newline, as it's the input separator, can be set to a NUL byte to slurp a file: `$/ = "\0"; $a = <$fh>;`. :-)

Comment: @andlrc Completely agree, most of these are to be used secretly (make better bugs that way).  I do use `local $/`, mostly in `$file = do { ... };`, also so that I can scope that one-time `$fh` as well. The `$.` is ocassionally exactly what's needed.  Didn't know about `$=` (or forgot very successfully :).  I think I should read through all of them again, it's been a long while.

Comment: @zdim  @ andlrc how to to update and add the blank cells in the same "filename" instead of sending result to a newer file " output " ?

Comment: @predictive  I've added this to the end of the post. In short, you add `-i` switch (to either version) and then the input file itself is changed instead of printing to screen.

Answer (score 2):

Take your pick:

```
$ awk '{printf "%34s\n", $0}' file
                         125552552
                         126382233
                         454654654
                         548652545
                         876544545

$ awk '{printf "%25s%s\n", "", $0}' file
                         125552552
                         126382233
                         454654654
                         548652545
                         876544545

$ awk '{printf "%*s\n", length()+25, $0}' file
                         125552552
                         126382233
                         454654654
                         548652545
                         876544545

$ awk 'BEGIN{s=sprintf("%25s","")} {printf "%s%s\n", s, $0}' file
                         125552552
                         126382233
                         454654654
                         548652545
                         876544545
```

Comment: + for the `%*s`... always learn from u.